# How to detect device platform and change link url using JavaScript in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, phonegap-build

I have a navigation link in my html that is supposed to open different links based on which device it is being viewed on ie: android, ios, desktop.. Some posts recommend using platform.js, but I am not sure how it can be put to use in my requirement.

Please help.

PS: I am working purely with JS implementation of phonegap and using the build service from adobe. Hence, cannot use cordvoa plugins.

Comment: I dont understand why you can not use plugins?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Cordova's built in device info.

```
if (device.platform.toLowerCase() == 'ios'){
    // Do Something
} else if(device.platform.toLowerCase() == 'android'){
    // Do Something else
} else {
    // Do something for desktop
}
```

You do mention AngularJS, just in case you are using Ionic, they have something similar:

```
if (ionic.Platform.isIOS())){
    // Do Something
} else if (ionic.Platform.isAndroid())){
    // Do Something else
} else {
    // Do something for desktop
}
```